# pyenv-win some commands give "no such command"

Tags: pyenv

I have installed pyenv on my windows 11 machine. Not all of the commands work but some do.
These commands give output which I expect:
`pyenv version`
`pyenv versions`

When I try pyenv versions I get:

```
  3.6.8-amd64
* 3.8.2-amd64 (set by C:\Users\myname\.pyenv\pyenv-win\version)
```

When I try pyenv --version I get the error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
pyenv
```

When I try pyenv update I get the error:

```
pyenv: no such command `update'
```

I checked pyenv commands and get this list:

```
--version
commands
duplicate
exec
export
global
help
install
local
rehash
shell
shims
uninstall
version
versions
whence
which
```

I don't know why `update` is not there/installed. It looks like `--version` should work but it doesn't.

When I check my environment PATH variable, I have these two entries:

```
C:\Users\myname\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin
C:\Users\myname\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims
```

I've thought about uninstalling/removing pyenv and starting over, but I think that would mean that I would also have to install my two exiting versions of python again.